# Internationalization Maven application

Tags: java, maven

Actually, I've created two files (MessageBundle_fr_BE and MessageBundle_us_US) where I put the different text to translate to internationalize my application

My problem is when I launch the application, I've following error :

```
Problem accessing /MyServlet. Reason:

Can't find bundle for base name MessageBundle, locale fr_FR

Caused by:

java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name MessageBundle, locale fr_FR
at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1499)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1322)
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:796)
at com.application.myGoogleAppEngine.Internationale.<init>(Internationale.java:13)
at com.application.myGoogleAppEngine.Internationale.getInstance(Internationale.java:18)
at com.application.myGoogleAppEngine.MyServlet.doPost(MyServlet.java:52)
at com.application.myGoogleAppEngine.MyServlet.doGet(MyServlet.java:30)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
```

The project structure is below :

```
- src
  - main
    - webapp
      - images
      - js
      - stylesheets
      - resources
          MessageBundle_fr_FR.properties
          MessageBundle_us_US.properties
      - WEB-INF
        - appengine-web.xml
        - logging.properties
        - web.xml
       - index.jsp
    - java
      - com.application.myGoogleApp
   - test

- target
- pom.xml
- nbActions.xml
- README.md
```

And a part of my pom.xml to include 'src/main/webapp/resources' directory:

```
<configuration>
   <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
   <webResources>
<!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
    <resource>
    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
    </resource>
    <resource>
    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources</directory>
    </resource>
   </webResources>
</configuration>
```

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Comment: So, do you have `MessageBundle_fr_FR`, or `MessageBundle_fr_BE`?

Answer (score 0):

`ResourceBundle.getBundle` will only look in the classpath.  It has no knowledge of .war files or servlets.  You must place the .properties files in WEB-INF/classes.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are using maven archetypes. So, I suggest to have template below:

```
src/main/java
src/main/resources
   -MessageBundle_fr_FR.properties
   -MessageBundle_us_US.properties
src/main/webapp
```

You must create **src/main/resources** and move your properties to this folder.